# using - in cell data while format cells is Number

Tags: excel, number-formatting

When I select 'Number' for format cell and I type for example '3-2' data will changes to 42431.
[image]

what is 42431 mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel is trying to interpret the number as a date. This is because of the dash which is used.

42431 is a dateserial which represents a date, in this case 03/02/2016 (American date format - mm/dd/yyyy.

There is no such recognised number with a dash. If you wish to make it stay that way, you need to format as text

Comment: 32 would be **3-2** if a custom number format of 0-0 was applied. I don't see much use for this beyond display purposes but it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to do the calculation of 3-2 = 1 you need to add the = sign to the line (ie type =3-2)

The number as @macromarc says is dateserial, the number of days since 1st of January 1900 (number of 1 is 1st of Jan 1900). You can do arithmetic with dates where each 1 is one day, so date/24 is hours etc...